# Unable to reset proxy settings

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, proxy

After watching a video only available in a certain country using a proxy, I wanted to revert back to my regular connection. I went and removed it in my settings (Screenshot showing No proxy).

[image: Screenshot 1]

But the thing is that the phone is still using the proxy. So, I downloaded an app for proxy change (Name: "[Proxy Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lechucksoftware.proxy.proxysettings)")

[image: Screenshot]

Then, I noticed that the proxy is still there. I delete it, press ok. Still nothing changed. I reopen the app, and the proxy is back!!!

I can't figure out how to have NO proxy!!!!

Thanks.

NB: LG G3, not rooted, Android 5.0.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the router and the phone?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do after clearing all Proxy configuration settings from your phone is reboot your device. Also, if you're connected to a specific WiFi network, press and hold the network name and "Forget Network."  Re-configure your WiFi settings with its regular password and it will clear Proxy settings.